# where to get tutorial to create a Big Query Project?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery, google-bigquery-storage-api, pybigquery

Want to learn about path from where to start and finish everything to create my first Big Query project

I Searched for tutorial but got nothing useful, so please guide me how can I learn from beginner to advance big query project so that I can create one advance big query project to spend my free $300 free which I got from creating account.